# Is there a way I can use a node js library in php?

Tags: php, node.js, gun

Is there a way I can use a Node JS library in php?
I’m thinking of the gun library in particular

https://gun.eco/

Comment: You can embed V8 in PHP, but you probably don't want to do this. It might be easier to run a separate node.js service and have your PHP service call it via some API.

Comment: It's better to call nodejs script from php, instead of using in php

Comment: How do I call a nodejs script in php?

Answer (score 0):

@desbest it might be easier to use a PHP version of GUN.

One does not exist yet, but people have ported GUN to other languages in just a few hours or days.

Here is a link on how, with a video where I port GUN in as short as 30 min:

https://gun.eco/docs/Porting-GUN